# Creation of a news flux with MySQL, select from 3 tables based on one providing table names and ids

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I'm trying to create a news flux with MySQL... for that, I have one table 'action' which records anytime an insert or an update is made in one of 3 other tables ('article','commentaire','auteur'). Now, I have in this first table 'action' 4 columns :

- id_action (which allows to know in order when action have been taken)
- action (add/update)
- table (name of one of the 3 other table)
- id_table (corresponding id in the upper table)

The 3 other tables have different columns names and contents, thus, I have :

- table 'article' with columns 'id', 'titre', 'contenu', 'categorie'
- table 'commentaire' with columns 'id', 'contenu'
- table 'auteur' with columns 'id', 'prenom', 'presentation', 'localisation'

I've tried with joins like:

```
SELECT ar.*,co.*,au.*
FROM 'action' AS ac
LEFT JOIN ac.table AS tbl ON ac.id_table = tbl.id
```

... but it didn't give anything as table 'ac.table' doesn't exist... (actually I hoped maybe it's going to take the name of the table and would replace it in the JOIN... :p

Thus, after 2-3 trial without success, I finally found something working but the latter is quite consuming and slow and I'm looking for a better solution...
the solution I found is made of 4 functions:

```
function showAllAction(){
   $preprequete = "SELECT id_table, table
   FROM 'action'";

   $requete = $this->pdo->prepare($preprequete);
   if ($requete->execute()) {
       $result = $requete->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $requete->closeCursor();
       return $result;
   }else{ die(print_r($requete->errorInfo()));} 
   return false;
}
```

followed by a foreach

```
$actions = $this->showAllAction();
foreach ($actions as $value){
   if($value['table']=='article'){
      $article = $this->showArticle($value['id_table']);
      echo $article['titre'];
   }elseif($value['table']=='commentaire'){
      $commentaire = $this->showCommentaire($value['id_table']);
      echo $commentaire['contenu'];
   }else{
      $auteur = $this->showAuteur($value['id_table']);
      echo $auteur['prenom'];
   }
}
```

where the différentes functions are simple SELECT like (following codes are just for illustrating, I have removed all none needed stuff to go to the point):

```
function showArticle($id_table){
   "SELECT titre, contenu, categorie
   FROM 'article'
   WHERE id = :id_table"
}
function showCommentaire($id_table){
   "SELECT contenu
   FROM 'commentaire'
   WHERE id = :id_table"
}
function showAuteur($id_table){
   "SELECT prenom, presentation, localisation
   FROM 'auteur'
   WHERE id = :id_table"
}
```

This, if anyone have a more efficient way to do what's needed, all answers are welcome! JOIN, conditionals, I have no idea what could do the trick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick a couple of `datetime` columns on each table, one for `creation_time` and one for `update_time`. See [this link][http://twopieceset.blogspot.com.au/2007/12/best-practices-5-ws-of-database-design.html] for a more detailed explanation.

You can create a view to simplify your chronological lookup, such as:

```
create or replace view recent_updates as 
select 'article' as `table`, article_id from article 
where update_time > now() - interval 1 day 
union all
select 'comment' as `table`, comment_id from comment 
where update_time > now() - interval 1 day 
union all
...
order by update_time desc
limit 1000
;
```

This will stay fast even as your database grows and doesn't require a separate tracking table. Don't forget to index the time columns!

(Note: Added a new answer since this wouldn't fit in a comment)

Comment: that's interesting! i didn't think of creating columns for creation AND updates, for creation only but update columns maybe helpful, in my select, i have added to your example a condition if update is null, then date_last_move = creation data, else date_last_move = update data and it works as needed! :) thanks much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me what you're trying to achieve here - is this an audit trail of some kind? I really recommend you avoid this table structure, you'll run into big performance problems when the data sets get larger. Try using one "history" table per data table, for example `article_actions` and `comment_actions` etc.

In any case here is a query that will do roughly the same thing you're doing but in plain SQL, it should be faster as you save all the database round trips (but still I don't recommend you use this actions table):

```
select ac.`table`, ar.title
from action ac join article ar on ac.table_id = ar.article_id
where `table` = 'article'
union all
select ac.`table`, co.content
from action ac join comment co on ac.table_id = co.comment_id
where `table` = 'comment'
union all
select ac.`table`, au.name
from action ac join author au on ac.table_id = au.author_id
where `table` = 'author'
;
```

Full example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb31e

Comment: thanks much for your answer! actually, i'm trying to do like a newspaper but on a website where people can update their profil, add articles, comment articles and i m trying to create something where people don't need to waste time to look for all changes but will find in on a 'news' page all changes in last 24h for example... i m trying all changes to be put chronologicaly and not per activity (profil update, comment add, article add, etc...) that's why one 'history' table per data table won't work i think because informations won't be given in a time order...?